# jquery populate select after select after selection is made

Tags: jquery, select, user-input

What is the functionality called. I am seeking to find what the coined term is for having

3-5 select boxes for example. Where one Select pending on the choice picked there populates another select, and so on down the line. I want to give someone a demo concept of what I am talking about but have no idea where to look for one. I know I can find this option on something like ebay when I am selling something, or on a car dealership when I am looking for a car starting by year make or model. But I want to take something already made and apply concept of what we are building currently to show as an example for what we are doing and how it will be of use to us. But I dont want ot have to build the whole thing from scratch unless I get the ok to do so.

So anyone know what it would be called so I can search for it in google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [jquery chained selects](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=jquery+chaining+selects). There are plenty of pages ([plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/selectchain) and tutorials) to help you on your way.